# Method to add items to Listbox c# using a combobox name as argument

Tags: c#

I need help with understanding how to use a variable name inside a foreach

```
        {....
private void populateUsage (string[] stringlist, unknown data type that is the combobox name)
        {
            string[] lineOfContents = stringlist;
            foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
            {
                comboboxname.Items.Add(line);
            }
}
```

what data type to use when passing the name of a combobox ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried `ComboBox`? Is this winforms or what?

Comment: you want to ask how to iterate a ComboBox using a foreach statement?

Comment: @NicoRiff OP is trying to create a combobox parameter, but doesn't know the type name.

Comment: `private void populateUsage (string[] stringlist, ComboBox  comboboxname)`

Comment: @itsme86 thanks. OP please explain a little mor what is it what you want to do and why you need the ComboBox as a parameter. It does not seem a good idea.

Comment: Wow! that was fast.... ComboBox is the data type.... You guys are great

Comment: @NicoRiff ... indeed its not a good idea, especially after i saw the suggestions posted here.. thank you kind sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void populateUsage (string[] stringlist, ComboBox comboboxname)
        {
            string[] lineOfContents = stringlist;
            foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
            {
                comboboxname.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
```

That said, I wouldn't mess with the `ComboBox` `ItemArray` directly like that over an `array` of `strings`.  There's a faster way:

```
private void populateUsage (string[] stringlist, ComboBox comboboxname)
{  comboboxname.DataSource = stringList.ToList();  }
```

Comment: DataSource and ToList puts all the strings on the listbox at one time? I'll try this, definitely a better approach.. Thank you

Comment: The faster way works great  user1895086... thanks a mil

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are asking for the type name for your combobox.  If you are using WinForms, it is probably [`System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx).  If you have `using System.Windows.Forms;` in the file already you can probably just use `ComboBox`.

Comment: Yes, Winforms, but i may eventually convert this to a webformat later on, wonder how simple (or hard ) that is